# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: "Адресат вызова создал исключение."

Tags: c#, wpf

На событии `TextChanged` возникает ошибка

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: “Адресат вызова создал
>   исключение.” Внутреннее исключение NullReferenceException: Ссылка на
>   объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка

```
Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="106*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="169*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="47,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" TextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="149" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="269"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Добавьте больше кода. Например, код разметки.

Comment: Скорее всего TextBox2 равен null, т.е. по какой-то причине не подвязался.

Comment: добавил разметку

Comment: Что-нибудь где-нибудь еще с `TextBox2` завязано?

Comment: нет, это весь код. остальное удалил с проекта

Comment: @nick_n_a тоже так подумал, но причин для этого совсем нет...

Comment: Перезапустил VS, cоздал новый проект на всякий случай – всё то же самое.

Comment: Это тестовый проект? Залейте плиз на какой-нибудь файлообменник и пришлите ссылку

Comment: Вот проект http://rgho.st/7fvRqbv5X   ответ Vardan Vardanyan помог, хотя все заминусовали

Comment: @АндрейДиневич: А где вы подписываетесь на event? Небось до `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: @VladD не понимаю о чем речь, я новичок. Если правильно понял, события лежат после `InitializeComponent` можете в проекте глянуть

Comment: @АндрейДиневич: У меня на работе заблокирован rghost, лучше опубликуйте ваш конструктор в вопросе.

Comment: опубликовал весь код, но проблема уже решена в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перепишите код вот так!

```
  private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (TextBox2 != null)
        {
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

При первом визове этого события у вас еще не создана екземпляр `MainWindow`,следовательно и еще не работала функция `InitializeComponent()` и вы пытетесь получить еще не созданную `TextBox2`.

Comment: Господи, что это?..

Comment: Если `InitializeComponent()` не сработала, то как появился `TextBox1` и тем более подписка на `TextChanged` событие?!

Comment: Но... зачем перехватывать NRE, если можно просто проверить на null? Кроме того, ваш вариант с возможной генерацией исключения и последующим его перехватом довольно дорогая операция, особенно не стоит этого делать в обработчиках событий. И как подсказывают выше, это не решает проблему автора.

Comment: читайте о `InitializeComponent()` вот здесь http://stackoverflow.com/a/245881/7198805  и посмотрите  ваш код здесь http://stackoverflow.com/a/247018/7198805  который сгенерировал VS думаю будет понятно почему `TextBox2` получает `null`

Comment: СРАБОТАЛО ! )))

Comment: И первый вариант `try` `catch` тоже работал.

Comment: знаю но так правильно в этом случайи читай коментарый написано  @Nikita-ой,первый вариант "довольно дорогая операция"

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что, как правильно замечает @Vardan Vardanyan, интерпретация XAML, а значит, назначение обработчиков событий и привязка имён происходит во время выполнения `InitializeComponent`. При этом порядок этих операций не определён. В вашем случае порядок был следующим:

- установился обработчик `TextChanged`
- установилось значение `Text` в `"TextBox"`, при этом вызвался обработчик
- далее переменной `TextBox2` должно было быть присвоено значение, соответствующее текстбоксу, но это не успело произойти, т. к. на предыдущем шаге случилось исключение.

(Заметьте, что стандарта на порядок выполнения этих операций нет, любой порядок возможен.)

Вы можете игнорировать событие во время `InitializeComponent`, проверяя `TextBox2` на равенство `null`. Но более чистым решением мне кажется подписка на событие *после* отработки `InitializeComponent`. Для этого нужно убрать `TextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"` из XAML и добавить в конструктор:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TextBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1_TextChanged;
    TextBox1_TextChanged(null, null); // обновить значение прямо сейчас
}
```